# IIS PHP use connection string from web.config

Tags: php, iis, connection-string

We use a string defined in a connect.php, but now we have some silverilght enabled services that make use of the web.config in IIS for their connection strings.

So rather than have the connection string in two places, can I access the one in web.config from PHP? That would also make it easier for end user to change.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's a very old thread but recently I've encountered similar problem. I am just gonna share my solution for whoever needs it. It served my purpose 100%, hope it helps you as well.

In my web.config connection string node looks like:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="sqlDB" connectionString="Server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx; Database=db_name; User Id=sqlserver_user_name; password=sqlserver_password;Max Pool Size=2000;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I wrote the following PHP Code to retrieve sql server connection information to use it in PHP

```
<?php
    // start get connection string from web.config
    $xml =  simplexml_load_file("../Web.config") or die("Error: Cannot create object"); 
    //in my case web.config is in previous directory
    $array = json_decode(json_encode((array) $xml), 1);

    $server = "";
    $database = "";
    $user = "";
    $password = "";

    $fullString = ($xml->connectionStrings->add[0]["connectionString"]);

    $strArr = explode(";", $fullString);

    $arrCount = count($strArr);
    $connArr[]="";
    for($x=0;$x<$arrCount-1;$x++){
        $aS = explode("=",$strArr[$x]);
        $connArr+=array(strtolower(trim($aS[0])) => trim($aS[1]));
    }
    $server = $connArr["server"];
    $database = $connArr["database"];
    $user = $connArr["user id"];
    $password = $connArr["password"];
    // end get connection string from web.config

    $connectionInfo = array( "UID"=>$user,                            
                             "PWD"=>$password,                            
                             "Database"=>$database,
                             "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8"); 

    /* Connect using SQL Server Authentication. */  
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $server, $connectionInfo); 
?>
```

FYI: In my case web.config and php files were in the same domain and under same root directory. If you are working in a cross domain environment you should first think of reading web.config from a remote location but that's not a wise decision for security reasons.

Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear that Burgi.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

- Make sure the web server process has access to the file. You could put in a link that is accessible to the webserver process.
- web.config is just a xml file. You can use the snippet I provided as a example or base to read the file and adjust it to your needs.

Snippet:

```
public function Load( $xmlfile )
{
  if ( is_readable( $xmlfile ) ) {
    $config = $this->xml2array( simplexml_load_file( $xmlfile ) );
}
```